Could my aloe plant die or the leaf turn brown if a hole was stabbed into it?
Some gel came out of the leaf and there's a yellowish film dried up over the hole.

It's a wound and will leave a scar.  No big deal. If there area many holes in a leaf and it may dry up and go brown in which case it can be removed.
If the leaf dies it will come cleanly off the stem if you grasp it firmly at the stem and pull
